# Default terminal text and background both black

Tags: 12.04, command-line, default, colors

Upgraded to 12.04 and default terminal is black text on black background.  I can right-click in the terminal and change the color, but the "Back Up" window is also black on black.

Answer (score 1):

the gnome-terminal settings are stored in

```
~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/
```

either delete that folder (will reset to defaults on next start of the terminal program) or edit the files with your favourite text editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can change everything in the Gnome-terminal by editing the profile; if you haven't changed the profile, it will be the "default" profile.

Choose "Edit" in the terminal menubar, and choose the "Colors" tab, or the "Background" tab, and make your changes there.